# Convert numbers with parentheses around to negative numbers

Tags: excel

I have Excel data that has parentheses around negative values, but Excel does not see them as negative values, it seems to take them as text. E.g. trying to sum cells that have ($25.00) and $50.00 gives #VALUE! error.

The data is imported from a csv file.

It's not a formatting issue, changing negative value formatting does not change anything. So, how do I convert these values to actual negative numbers?

Thanks.

Here is some sample data in case someone wants it. So the values in parentheses are supposed to be negative numbers but seem to be text at the moment.

```
($25.00)
 $50.00
($35.00)
($15.00)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replace `$` with nothing, `)` with nothing and `(` with `-`.

Answer (score 1):

Type `1` into an unused cell. Copy it. Select the numbers that are stored as text and select Home - Clipboard - Paste - Paste Special - Multiply. Delete the `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Complete syntax for converting numbers like ($6,437.55) to money data type:

```
CASE WHEN IsNumeric(Replace(Replace(Replace([INPUT-COLUMN-NAME], ',', ''),')',''),'(','-')) = 1 Then Cast(Replace(Replace(Replace([INPUT-COLUMN-NAME], ',', ''),')',''),'(','-') AS Money) ELSE 0 END As [OUTPUT-COLUMN-NAME]
```

This can be used directly in SQL statement like
Select ColumnA, CASE WHEN as above, ColumnC
From Table.. join etc.

You can also define a function like (which comes with a performance penalty though) and use function in select statement.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ConvertStringToMoneyType(@input_Number varchar(50))
RETURNS MONEY
AS
BEGIN

Declare @Output_Number money = 0

Set @Output_Number = CASE WHEN IsNumeric(Replace(Replace(Replace(@input_Number, ',', ''),')',''),'(','-')) = 1 Then 
        Cast(Replace(Replace(Replace(@input_Number, ',', ''),')',''),'(','-') AS Money) ELSE 0 END

RETURN @Output_Number


END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two columns and create a heading as the first row is excluded.  One for Withdrawals and one for Deposits for bank transactions for example.  Use the formulas before for the Deposit column and for the Withdrawn column for all rows.

Be sure the formatting is set to Currency instead of Accounting to remove the parenthesis for negative currency entries.

Withdrawn Column:
=IF(B2<1,B2,"")

Deposit Column:
=IF(B2<1,"",B2)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).